# Currently creating a datapack for a custom recipe but i dont know how to name my result after the items have been put in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

So I'm using a JSON editor to create my crafting recipe and at the moment I can't seem to figure out how to name my result item.
Any help?

**Code:**

```
{

    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        "#W#",
        "DED",
        "L L"
    ],
    "key": {
        "#": {
            "item": "minecraft:lapis_block"
        },
        "W": {
            "item": "minecraft:water_bucket"
        },
        "D": {
            "item": "minecraft:diamond_block"
        },
        "E": {
            "item": "minecraft:diamond_leggings"
        },
        "L": {
            "item": "minecraft:lily_pad"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:diamond_leggings",
        "count": 1
    },
    "group": "Armour"
}
```

Comment: i see but like in my command i want to name my diamond leggings "SUPER PANTS" but do i do like "item": "minecraft:diamond_leggings, name: SUPER_PANTS",  or is it like not possible

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: A very good workaround has been suggested in [the topmost duplicate of the original question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361015/datapacks-question-craft-enchanted-items).