# I need a Custom crafting with the option of destroying specific blocks (Canbreak command)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a Custom crafting with the option of destroying specific blocks (Canbreak command)

I need this creation but with the addition on the created object status "canbreak oak_log"

```
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        " # ",
        "W  ",
        "   "
    ],
    "key": {
        "#": {
            "item": "minecraft:flint"
        },
        "W": {
            "item": "minecraft:wooden_axe"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:wooden_axe",
        "count": 1
    }
}


I tried to do it this way but i have no effect

{
    "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
    "pattern": [
        " # ",
        "W  ",
        "   "
    ],
    "key": {
        "#": {
            "item": "minecraft:flint"
        },
        "W": {
            "item": "minecraft:wooden_axe"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "item": "minecraft:wooden_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_wood"]}",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: What Minecraft edition are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java Edition

Comment: Still no NBT in custom crafting recipes, same in 1.15.2 as in 1.14.4.

Comment: A very good workaround has been suggested in [the topmost duplicate of the original question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361015/datapacks-question-craft-enchanted-items).